# Multinomial coefficients (general inequality).

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

Fix $s, n$ in $\mathbb{N}.$ Let $n_1,..., n_s$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $n_k\geq 1.$ Set $N= \sum_{k=1}^sn_k.$ I want to prove that
$$\sum_{m_1+...+m_s=n}\prod_{k=1}^s(m_k+n_k)!\leq (n+N)!.$$

The simple case where $s=2$ is equivalent to prove that 
$$\sum_{m=0}^n (m+n_1)!(n-m+n_2)! \leq (n+N)!.$$
This can be proven by induction on $n;$ 
\begin{eqnarray}\sum_{m=0}^{n+1} (m+n_1)!(n+1-m+n_2)! &\leq&   (n+1+n_1)!n_2! +(n+N)\sum_{m=0}^n (m+n_1)!(n-m+n_2)! \\
&\leq& (n+N)! +(n+N)(n+N)! \\
&=& (n+1+N)! \end{eqnarray}
Any hint for the general case $s\geq 2?!$

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything (directly) to do with multinomial coefficients. Perhaps you could clarify the relationship?

Comment: (It also doesn't seem to have anything to do with abstract algebra.)

Comment: In fact, if you divide by the right hand member, you will get inside the sum the term $\binom{|M|+N}{m_1+n_1,...., m_s+n_s}^{-1},$ where $M = (m_1, ..., m_s).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use induction on $s$: for any $m_s'\ge 0$,
$$
\sum_{m_s+m_{s+1} = m_s'} (m_s + n_s)!(m_{s+1}+n_{s+1})! \le (m_s' + n_s')!,
$$
where $n_s' = n_{s} + n_{s+1}$. Therefore, 
$$
\sum_{m_1+...+m_{s+1}=n}\prod_{k=1}^{s+1}(m_k+n_k)! \\= \sum_{m_1+...+m_{s-1}+m_s'=n}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{s-1}(m_k+n_k)!\right)\sum_{m_s+m_{s+1} = m_s'} (m_s + n_s)!(m_{s+1}+n_{s+1})! \\\le \sum_{m_1+...+m_{s-1}+m_s'=n}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{s-1}(m_k+n_k)!\right) (m_s'+n_s')!
$$
etc.

Comment: Just to be sure that I got it, you used $\sum_{m_1+...+m_{s+1}= n} = \sum_{m_1+...m_{s-1}+m'_s =n} \sum_{m_s+m_{s+1} =m'_s }$ ?

Comment: @A.MONET, sure I did. I've elaborated a bit; check now.

Comment: Seems to be done ! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For any $\ell$ define the formal power series
$$F_\ell(x)=\ell!+(1+\ell)!x+(2+\ell)!x^2+(3+\ell)!x^3+\cdots.$$
In terms of this power series, the left and right sides of the inequality are
$$ \sum_{m_1+\cdots+m_s=n}\prod_{k=1}^s (m_k+n_k)!=[x^n]F_{n_1}(x)\times\cdots\times F_{n_s}(x)$$
and $$(n+n_1+\cdots+n_s)!=[x^n]F_{n_1+\cdots+n_s}(x) .$$
In the $s=2$ case, the OP already did all the hard work to show
$$ [x^n]F_{n_1}(x)\times F_{n_2}(x)\le[x^n]F_{n_1+n_2}(x).$$
The rest follows by combining partial sums with the next term, like this:
\begin{eqnarray*}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
  [x^n]F_{n_1}(x)\times\cdots\times F_{n_s}(x) &\le& [x^n]F_{n_1+n_2}(x)\times F_{n_3}(x)\times\cdots\times F_{n_s}(x) \\
    &\le& [x^n]F_{n_1+n_2+n_3}(x)\times F_{n_4}(x)\times\cdots\times F_{n_s}(x) \\
    &\vdots&\\
    &\le& [x^n]F_{n_1+\cdots+n_s}(x) .
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: What does the term $[x^n]$ represent ? Maybe you mean the coefficient of $x^n$ and in which step did you use the assumption $n_k \geq1$?

Comment: Right, $[x^n]f(x)$ means the coefficient of $x^n$ in $f(x)$. Also, I didn't use $n_k\ge1$, although you might have in the $s=2$ case. The inequality might still hold with $n_k\ge0$.

Comment: Then, if you take, for example, $s=2$ and $n_1 =  n_s = 0,$ the left hand member will be $n! + (n-1)! + 2(n-2)! + .... +n!  > (n+0)!$

Comment: @A.MONET, I believe $n_k\ge 1$ in the OP. This answer is in essence the induction on $s$. I don't like the emphasis on generating functions, but I do like that it unveils why the induction argument works: because of the convolution structure of the left-hand side.

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question: What does OP abbreviate ?

Comment: I think OP is taken to mean either Original Post or Original Poser.

Comment: @zhoraster Your proof is actually based on the initial case $s=2,$ where the inductive inequalities require explicitly that $n_k \geq 1.$